# Difference between $X\sim Y$ and $X\overset{d}{=}Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, random-variables, intuition

Let us suppose that there is a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}\right)$ and two random variables $X,Y$ defined on it. Which is the difference between
$$X\overset{d}{=}Y\tag{1}$$
and
$$X\sim Y\tag{2}$$
?

---

---

Does $(1)$ mean that the two random variables are exactly the "same object" (e.g. $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$), while $(2)$ denotes a situation like $X\sim\mathcal{N}(1,2.4)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2.6)$ (that is, both $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed, but with two different parameters)?

Comment: They mean the same thing which is equality in distribution.

Comment: On a book I read that $(1)$ refers to equivalent random variables, while $(2)$ refers to random variables with the same distribution. Are such "descriptions" the same thing? @StedanHansen

Comment: The first one is definitely equality in distribution. The second one is a bit more ad hoc, but out of context I'd probably understand it the same way.

Comment: what do you mean by "a bit more ad hoc"? @Ian

Comment: I could see it being redefined by a particular author to mean something else. Doing that with $\overset{d}{=}$ would be very bad form.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing: "Equivalence" between random variables isn't really well-defined as two random variables can be equivalent in more than one way: they can be equal $\omega$-for-$\omega$, they can be equal almost surely and they can be equal in distribution. But I haven't seen $\sim$ and $\overset{d}{=}$ meaning anything else than equality in distribution.